# Testng RetryListener is not FAILING the test case after the maximum attempt

Tags: java, maven, selenium, junit, testng

I have used the TestNG RetyListener by following this link http://www.seleniumeasy.com/testng-tutorials/execute-only-failed-test-cases-using-iretryanalyzer and then included the listener in testng.xml.

1. When run the test cases as TestNG suite this was working fine and tests are marking as FAILURE after the maximum retry

```
Selected environment: QA
Retrying test testcase1 with status FAILURE for the 1 time(s).
testcase1 skipped.
Retrying test testcase1 with status FAILURE for the 2 time(s).
testcase1 skipped.
Retrying test testcase1 with status FAILURE for the 3 time(s).
testcase1 skipped.
ERROR: testcase1 has failed
```

2. When run it with maven command (mvn clean test), the tests are marked as skipped after the maximum retry which causing the issues with Allure report generation

```
Retrying test testcase1 with status FAILURE for the 1 time(s).
testcase1 skipped.
Retrying test testcase1 with status FAILURE for the 2 time(s).
testcase1 skipped.
Retrying test testcase1 with status SKIP for the 3 time(s).
```

Need help to get the same behavior as like TestNG when using Maven

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your TestNG dependency to the last version:

```
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>6.14.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```